# How to access Axis2 web service running on localhost from another system?

Tags: java, web-services, ip, tomcat7, apache-axis

I have made a very basic web service(Axis2) using Eclipse which is running successfully on localhost with URL `"localhost:8080/webApp/services/Hello?wsdl"`. Now as per my need I have to access this web service from another system browser. What do I write in the URL Address bar of the browser?

Comment: Try `<your IP address>:8080/webApp/services/Hello?wsdl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both the system have to belong to the same network then just replace the localhost with the ip address of the hosting system in URL

```
URL "localhost:8080/webApp/services/Hello?wsdl"
```

becomes
ip of the system hosting the web service = 192.111.111.111

```
URL "192.111.111.111:8080/webApp/services/Hello?wsdl"
```

Comment: @vikas : if anyone is accredited for it , then its STACKOVERFLOW